# How to user SingleOrDefault with different string letter case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is for the intranet. When I search for the username it comes out with lower case.

When I search for the username within the table it never finds the username because it seems it needs to be capitalized as it is also capitalized in the table.

Is there a way to make this work to work on any case when searching the table using SingleOrDefault?

```
var userNamenew = userName.Split('\\')[1]; //this equals to 'namel'
//var userNamenew = "NameL"; //this work
var CurrentUser = employee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userNamenew);
```

Comment: What about just toLower or toUpper at each side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

`employee.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == userNamenew.ToLower());`

And then you're comparing two lower case strings